# Rename [openerp] to [odoo]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The OpenERP project has been renamed to Odoo, so I propose to rename [openerp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/openerp) to [odoo](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/odoo).

The tag wiki should also be updated accordingly mentioning the old name(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​